# Looking for third party charting options for ColdFusion

Tags: coldfusion, charts

A project I am working on makes extensive use of CFCHART. We have run into quite a few usage and performance issues with CFCHART, so I have been tasked to look at some third-party solutions to try out and recommend. Anybody have some reviews and recommendations they'd care to share?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you to everyone for these suggestions! This gives me a good list of applications to work with. Since there is no one "right" answer for a question like this I made sure to note each answer as useful.

Answer (score 4):

Consider outputting the raw data and using JavaScript / Canvas to generate the charts on the fly. The load is the given to the client.
This makes it easier for screenreaders and people who like to save the data to access it as well.

Some JS charting libraries:

- http://code.google.com/apis/chart/
- http://omnipotent.net/jquery.sparkline/
- http://code.google.com/p/flot/
- http://codecanyon.net/item/graphup-jquery-plugin/108025?redirect_back=true&ref=1stwebdesigner&clickthrough_id=23945276
- http://www.highcharts.com/

Answer (score 2):

Not dependent on your server side technology (e.g. irrelevant to the fact that you're using CF), I have recently started playing around with HighCharts (http://www.highcharts.com/), and have been very impressed.

Bear in mind, it's not free for commercial use, but you didn't specify as to any such restrictions.  Although their pricing seems pretty fair (see http://www.highcharts.com/license)

Answer (score 2):

The Wijmo jQuery library has some nice charting widgets. http://wijmo.com/

Answer (score 1):

We use [FusionCharts](http://www.fusioncharts.com/). They have a comprehensive set of chart and widget types (eg sparklines) and have a very slick, professional finish.

Answer (score 1):

ChartDirector is reasonable and is very advanced.  It generates image-based graphs and we don't have to worry about whether or not different browsers support various advanced HTML features or Flash.  You can download it, install and run it unlicensed and it will only add a little copyright in the bottom-right 20 pixels of the graph. (Licensing is inexpensive.) It comes with 239+ ColdFusion scripts so that you have plenty of sample code.  Their support forums is very active and helpful.

http://www.advsofteng.com/cdcoldfusion.html

Check out the gallery.  It has some very impressive samples.  You can create just about anything.

http://www.advsofteng.com/gallery.html

Answer (score 1):

You can try [jqChart](http://www.jqchart.com) as well.